# de.mobilej.ABridge: frozen class (cannot edit)

Tags: android

Suddenly I am getting this error when using unmock. A `gradle clean` is not helping:

```
Execution failed for task ':android:unMock'.
> de.mobilej.ABridge: frozen class (cannot edit)
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I have the same error now.

Comment: yea - just added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was happening when I was debugging a test with Android-Studio and executing tests with console at the same time